# Class with long name

Tags: java, android, exception, naming-conventions

Name of Exception class in Java  must have `Exception` suffix also describe its throwing situation. Now I have two exception classes in about primary external storage in `Android`:

```
/**
 * Thrown when Application tries to access primary external storage and it is not
 * available for write.This only depends on status of storage, for example media
 * not mounted,bad mounted, or ... .
 */
public class PrimaryExternalStorageIsNotReadyToWriteException extends Exception {
...
}

/**
 * Thrown when Application tries to write on a directory
 * of primary external storage that needs
 * {@link Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} permission but that
 * permission has not granted to the Application.
 */
public class WriteToPrimaryExternalStoragePermisionException extends RuntimeException {
...
}
```

As you see, names are long, but I can not remove `Exception` or `PrimaryExternalStorage` from names. Also I do not want to use `SecurityException` or other existing exceptions because those are general. I know long names are not forbidden but using and reminding them is hard. The only thing I can think is creating a package with name `primaryexternalstorageexceptions` and change names to `IsNotReadyToWriteException` and `WritePermisionException`. But is it a good way? And is there a better way to avoid those long names?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with these names.

Comment: @jangroth Thank you for your attention, really I had thought in about super and sub classes,but unfortunately one extends `Exception` and another extends `RuntimeException`.So I can not use this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `PrimaryExternalStorage` pretty often in your program, it seems ok to introduce (and document) an abbreviation like `PES` and use `PESIsNotReadyToWriteException`, `WriteToPESPermissionException` (or `PesIsNotReadyToWriteException`, `WriteToPesPermissionException` depending on your policy of using abbreviations in camelCased identifiers).

Note that `Is` in your first exception is definitely redundant. See, for example, JDK exceptions like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not `ArrayIndexIsOutOfBoundsException`.

Another thing which comes in mind is to make your exceptions somewhat more general like `PrimaryExternalStorageNotReadyException` (not ready for anything, not just write) and `PrimaryExternalStoragePermissionException` (actual missing permission were it write or read may be passed as exception parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your attention.In about your first suggestion, I am not sure because docs say: "Class names should be nouns, ... Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML)."

Answer (score -1):

Creating a separate package `primaryexternalstorageexceptions` for a single exception class is killing the concept of Packages in java. If you feel that there would be more than 5 or 6 Exception class that would be part of `primaryexternalstorageexceptions`, then you can got for it. I personally do not think to have a separate package.

I would suggest you to shorten the class name likewise:
`PrimaryExternalStorageIsNotReadyToWriteException` to `PrmyExtlStrgIsNotReadyToWriteException`

The standard is to what you have now, which is a long class name. Anyhow, the Exceptions are packaged and it will not be hard for you to go to a package and search for the class.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's an opinion. And IMO, your suggested "abbreviations" don't really accomplish any significant reduction in size, reduce readability, and make it even harder to remember, as the poster asked.